# "TransitionTo" affects page refresh in Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js

My ember application contains a parent route with two nested routes. After fetching the parent route's model I'll transition to one of the nested routes by default.

The router is as follows

```
this.resource('parent', {path: '/parent'}, function() {
    this.route('route1', {path: '/route1'});
    this.route('route2', {path: '/route2'});
});
```

In the parent route

```
redirect: function()
{
    this.transitionTo('parent.route1');
}
```

Now this works perfectly fine. But the problem arises when I refresh the page while being on the route "#/parent/route2".

Actually I should get the contents of "route2" but the transitionTo makes the route to render "route1". How can I handle this ?

In addition to this. I'm fetching the parent route's model in the nested routes by using "this.modelFor('parent')".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of having the redirect in `App.Parent`, have it in `App.ParentIndex`.

```
App.ParentIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  redirect: function() {
    return this.transitionTo('parent.route1');
  }
});
```

Demo http://emberjs.jsbin.com/pavomo/2/#/sales/orders/

Note that you get redirected to orders/4 by default if no subroute found.

Comment: I've a problem getting the parent route's model here. Previously in my "route1' I used to get the parent's model using "this.modelFor('parent')". But now "this.modelFor('parent.index')" doesn't seem to work.

Comment: I wrote a route for App.Parent too. And fetched the model in that. In App.ParentIndex route I handled the redirecting. Got the model in the child routes using "this.modelFor('parent')"